# Google Timezone API returning ZERO_RESULTS for some locations

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, timezone

We have an API which looks up the lat / long of an input address using the Google geocoding API. The `location` of the response of that is then fed to the [Google Timezone API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/intro).

As it turns out though, there are some locations which, while they do return a valid result from the geocoding api, return a ZERO_RESULTS error from the timezone API. Some of these are e.g. `690091,Vladivostok,Russia`, or country `BL` (Saint-Barthélemy).

Geocoding request:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=API-KEY-HERE&components=country%3ARU&address=690091%2CVladivostok

Timezone request:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?key=API-KEY-HERE&location=43.140489%2C131.858103&timestamp=0

This isn't listed in the documentation as a possibility.

My main question: is this a known problem with either timezones in general, or the google timezone API in general?

I'd expect that all valid lat / lngs would have a timezone, and with some googling I don't see any cases of a location not having a timezone. The Vladivostok example points to somewhere in the sea according to [google maps](https://www.google.nl/maps/place/43%C2%B008'25.8%22N+131%C2%B051'29.2%22E/@43.1135399,131.816324,12z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d43.140489!4d131.858103?hl=nl), but Saint-Barthélemy points right on the island ([api](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?key=API-KEY-HERE&location=17.90000000%2C-62.83333300&timestamp=0), [maps](https://www.google.nl/maps/place/17%C2%B054'00.0%22N+62%C2%B050'00.0%22W/@17.8968428,-62.8332399,16.48z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d17.9!4d-62.833333?hl=nl)).

Edit: As it turns out, I didn't read: the timezone api states "Note that time zone data may not be available for locations over water, such as oceans or seas." Does anyone know what the reason behind that is? Weirdness with country borders and international waters?

Answer (score 3):

The coordinate (43.140489,131.858103) that you apply in Timezone API appears to be located in the water.

Please have a look at this position in Geocoder tool:

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3D43.140489%252C131.858103%26nfw%3D0

The green cross shows the position of the coordinate.

Timezone API doesn't return results for waters.

I have seen very similar issues in the public issue tracker:

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=10885

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=10762

You should apply latitude longitude that is located on the land and additionally you can comment on the issue 10762. I believe this is a good feature request to have a TimeZone API within the waters owned by a country.